# What are capture interfaces in Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

I am really new to Wireshark, and I am little confused about the term **capture interface**. I see a list of about 9 to 10 so-called interfaces. What are they? I mean, I have only one Ethernet interface card and a wireless card, with each providing one interface, which makes two interfaces(?), doesn't it? But how is that Wireshark tells me there are 9 interfaces?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of those interfaces

Comment: @Michelz sorry, it says that I have to gain 10 reps before I can post an image :P

Comment: No problem. As MDMarra points out, those are "virtual interfaces", which exist on your system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are virtual interfaces that exist on your machine. If you do `ipconfig /all` you'll see tunnel adapters, wired adapters, wifi adapters, and possibly even virtual adapters for things like VirtualBox or VMWare Workstation.

There are more interfaces under the hood than just the two physical interfaces that you can see.